# Omitting Types Theorem for homogeneous model

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

> Let $L$ a countable language and $T$ a complete $L-$theory.  Let $p(x)\subseteq L$ a non-isolated consistent type. Is there an homogeneous model that omits the type?

The notion of homogeneity is the following:

> We say that $N$ is (elementarily) $\lambda$-homogeneous if every partial elementary map $k\colon N \to N$ of cardinality ${<}\lambda$ extends to an automorphism. We say that $N$ is homogeneous if it is $\lambda$-homogeneous and of cardinality $\lambda$.

I tried to follow the proof of the omitting types theorem with the construction of Löwenheim-Skolem and using the following Lemma:

> Let $L(A)$ countable. Let $p(x) \subseteq L(A)$ and suppose that $A$ does not isolate $p(x)$. Then, if $\psi(z)\in L(A)$ is consistent, $\psi(z)$ has a solution $a$ such that $A,a$ does not isolate $p(x)$.

I added the hypothesis in the inductive construction of a homogeneous model, but I can’t understand how to construct the chain.

If this is true, is it still true dropping the hypothesis of completeness of the theory?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: The word "homogeneous" is used in a few different ways in model theory. Can you clarify the definition of "homogeneous model" you have in mind?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I add the definition in the post

Comment: The question is much better now! I edited to improve the grammar and to include MathJax formatting. Please use MathJax in your future posts. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/7062).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an easy observation: If $T$ has a countable atomic model (equivalently, if isolated types are dense in the type space $S_n(T)$ for all $n$), then $T$ has a countable homogeneous model omitting $p(x)$, since countable atomic models are homogeneous and omit all non-isolated types.

But in general, it is not possible to find a homogeneous model omitting a given non-isolated type. I will give a counterexample. Thanks to Primo Petri for the simplification suggested in the comments.

Let $L$ be the language consisting of countably many binary relation symbols $(R_n)_{n\in \omega}$. Let $T$ be the $L$-theory asserting that each $R_n$ is a graph relation (symmetric and anti-reflexive). Let $T^*$ be the model companion of the above theory. $T^*$ is sometimes called the theory of "kaleidoscope random graphs".

Someone more concretely, note that for any finite sublanguage $L'\subseteq L$, the class of finite models of $T|_{L'}$ is a Fraïssé class. Writing $T_{L'}$ for the theory of the Fraïssé limit, we have that $T^* = \bigcup_{L'\subseteq_{\mathrm{fin}} L} T_{L'}$. Since each $T_{L'}$ has quantifier elimination, it follows that $T^*$ has quantifier elimination.

Let $p(x,y,x',y')$ be the type $$\{x\neq y, x'\neq y', (x\neq x')\lor (y\neq y'), (x\neq y') \lor (y\neq x')\}\cup \{R_n(x,y)\leftrightarrow R_n(x',y')\mid n\in \omega\}.$$
A realization of $p$ is a $4$-tuple $(a,b,a',b')$ such that $a\neq b$, $a'\neq b'$, $\{a,b\}\neq \{a',b'\}$, and the pairs $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a',b'\}$ agree on all graph relations $R_n$.

I claim that no homogeneous model of $T^*$ omits $p$. Let $M\models T^*$ be a homogeneous model. Let $a$, $b$, and $a'$ be three distinct elements. By quantifier elimination, there is a unique $1$-type over $\varnothing$ relative to $T^*$, so by homogeneity, there is an automorphism $\sigma\in \mathrm{Aut}(M)$ such that $\sigma(a) = a'$. Let $b' = \sigma(b)$. Note that $a\neq b$ implies $a'\neq b'$. Further, since $a'\notin \{a,b\}$, $\{a,b\}\neq \{a',b'\}$. And since $\sigma$ is an automorphism, we have $R_n(a,b) \leftrightarrow R_n(a',b')$ for all $n\in \omega$. So $(a,b,a',b')$ realizes $p$.

It remains to show that $p$ is non-isolated. One way to see this is with a probabilistic construction of models of $T^*$, which may also help motivate what's going on with this example.

Take the domain of our model $M$ to be $\omega$. For each pair $\{a,b\}$ of distinct elements of $\omega$, flip countably many fair coins independently. Set $R_n(a,b)$ (and $R_n(b,a)$, for symmetry) to be true if and only if the $n^{\text{th}}$ coin came up heads.

The resulting structure $M$ is almost surely a model of $T^*$, for essentially the same reason that the infinite Erdös-Rényi random graph is almost surely isomorphic to the [Rado graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph).

Further, $M$ almost surely omits $p$, which establishes that $p$ is non-isolated. For any $4$-tuple $(a,b,a',b')$ such that $a\neq b$, $a'\neq b'$, and $\{a,b\}\neq \{a',b'\}$, almost surely $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a',b'\}$ differ on some coin flip (the probability that the infinite sequence of coin flips for $\{a',b'\}$ agrees exactly with the infinite sequence of coin flips for $\{a,b\}$ is $0$). So almost surely $(a,b,a',b')$ fails to realize $p$. Since there are only  countably many such $4$-tuples, almost surely $p(x)$ is omitted.

Note that structures built in this probabilistic way are almost surely not homogeneous: If $a\neq a'$ in $G$, then almost surely there is no automorphism of $M$ moving $a$ to $a'$, since for any $b$ distinct from $a$ and $a'$, there is almost surely no $b'\neq a'$ such that $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a',b'\}$ agree on all their coin flips. So you can clearly see the tension between homogeneity and omitting $p$.

---

Caveat: The $p$ in my example is not a complete type. I think one could work a bit harder to find an example of a *complete* non-isolated type which cannot be omitted in any homogeneous model, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Kudos. It seems possible to work only with the sort $G$ and the type $p(x,y,z,w)=\{R_k(x,y)\leftrightarrow R_k(z,w)\ :\ k\in\omega\}$.

Comment: @PrimoPetri That was my original idea, but then I realized that $p$ is not complete. Now that I look at the question again, though, I see that the OP didn't specify that $p$ is complete. So maybe the simpler version would satisfy them.

Comment: @PrimoPetri But now I've realized that the type in my previous answer was not complete (because my assertion about quantifier elimination was not right). So I've adopted the simplification you suggested. Thanks!